# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number error even when i'm using bindParam instead of execute

Tags: php, mysql

I've been creating a post retrieval script in **PHP** which grabs both posts and reposts for a users feed. However, I've come across the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
```

So I went searching around and found that you cannot use multiple markers with the same name when passing them through `execute()` as an array (ie. `$query->execute(array(":foo" => "foo"))`). This can be found in **PHP**'s documentation on their official website [PHP - PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement.

What's strange is that I'm receiving this error despite using `bindParam` and not passing an array as a parameter of `execute`:

```php
function query($sql, $params = array()){
    if($query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        if(count($params)){
            foreach($params as $key => $param){
                if(substr($key, 0, 1) !== ":")
                    $key = ":" . $key;

                // notice me using bindParam
                // it would turn into something along the lines of
                // bindParam(":user", 12345, PDO::PARAM_INT)
                $query->bindParam($key, $param, is_numeric($param) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }

        try{
            // no array passed here
            $query->execute();
            $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            return $results;
        } catch(Exception $e){
            return $e;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$posts = array();
$offset = ($offset % 2 == 0 ? $offset : $offset - 1) / 2;

$_sql = [
    "SELECT upload_id FROM uploads WHERE upload_artist IN (SELECT following FROM followers WHERE follower = :user) OR upload_artist = :user AND upload_private = 0 AND upload_published = 1 ORDER BY upload_date desc LIMIT :offset, 7",
    "SELECT repost_id, repost_track FROM reposts WHERE repost_user IN (SELECT following FROM followers WHERE follower = :user) OR repost_user = :user ORDER BY repost_date desc LIMIT :offset, 7"
];
$params = ["user" => $user_id, "offset" => $offset];
foreach($_sql as $sql){
    array_push($posts, query($sql, $params));
}

var_dump($posts);
```

I'm almost certain that I've used multiple markers of the same name before using the same query function, so how do I fix this problem? I don't want to have to go the long way (using `?`) and having to do `[$user_id, $user_id, $user_id, $offset]` - because that's just ridiculous.

Comment: So... you're already aware what the issue is? I've never known it to work using multiple placeholders with the same name. I'm unsure why you think it's strange it would happen for both bindParam calls and execute. Also, you can use `bindParam` with`?` placeholders, you just have to specify the key of the placeholder (which looking at the docs start from 1).

Comment: Not sure if this is pertinent to this error message, but it's certainly pertinent if you ever solve this error message: `bindParam` binds ***by reference***. You'll end up with the last value of `$param` being applied to all placeholders. Use `bindValue` instead.

Comment: @deceze thanks for that! I'll switch it over now!